# Regular expression don't match with g flag

Tags: ruby, regex

please help me, i don't know what wrong with this regular expression.
`<div>\s*<strong>\s*Ціна[\s[:alpha:]\,\.]*:\s*<\/strong>\s*(\d+[\s\d]*.\d*)\s*грн[\s[:alpha:]\,\.]*<\/div>`
Without g flag i have 1 match, but with g flag `no matches`
Below part of searching text

```
<div><strong>Ціна продажу:</strong> 5 734 600.00 ГРН</div>
```

Comment: You can't parse HTML with Regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: use a DOM parser

Comment: please provide the rule you want to achieve in this searching text

Comment: @karthikselvaraj I just to want to match text providing in question by regex providing in question, but i don't know why without g flag regex has match and with g flag not

Comment: @Oleksii - Sorry, what is meant by g flag. I could't understand

Comment: @karthikselvaraj - This mean `/g` global searching, but i don't understand why not global searching has one match but global searching not.

Comment: @Oleksii Ruby regex does not use `g` flag. You need to use `String#scan(Regexp)` and make sure to use non-capturing groups, replace all `(` with `(?:`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - why i should use non-capturing group? I want to use some value from searching text later.

Comment: ok, then just use `scan`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks